# Этимология слова "ерепениться"

Tags: этимология

Вот интересно. В русском языке слова, начинающиеся на Е, вообще можно по пальцам подсчитать. А что же это за слово такое - "ерепениться" (упираться, показывать норов)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По Далю ЕРЕПЕНИТЬ кого, бить, сечь, наказывать телесно; | подзадоривать, поджигать. Ерепениться, чваниться, спесивиться, подымать нос. | Упрямиться, упорствовать, вздорить, хорохориться, ерошиться, ершиться. Вишь ты, индейский петух ерепенится! Ерепыжить кого, пск. бранить или тазать, ругать; -ся, сердиться, беситься. Еропа об. тул. надутый, чванный, самодовольный. Еропить тул. чваниться. Есть прозвание Еропкин. Ер(е)песить вят. нетерпеливо домогаться чего, настойчиво понуждать, торопить и упрашивать; | ербезить, егозить, елозить.

Современные толковые словари дают значение "упрямиться" и близкие к этому.

Что касается этимологии, то тут не все ясно. В. Даль, раз включил слово "еропа" в статью "ерепенить", соотносит эти слова ("ерепенить" от "еропа").

Этимологический словарь р.яз. (СПб) - от диалект. "ерепа" - надутый.

Этимологический словарь р.яз. (М) - сближение с "еропа" (хвастун) сомнительно. (у Фасмера эта же версия)

Этимологический словарь р.яз., 2004 - Вероятно суф. произв. от ера  "задира", "непоседа"

Вот такой разлад во мнениях.